# Pointer causes segmentation fault. (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program which has two dialogs. In my main dialog class I declared a pointer to the other dialog like such: ChildDialog *childDialog. However, when I try to use it for example childDialog->show() or try to use it to connect signals and slots between the two classes, my program crashes. Anyone know why? Did I declare the pointer incorrectly?

P.S. I have included the header file in the appropriate places. So I don't think that's the problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate the object--

```
ChildDialog *childDialog;
```

Just declares a pointer to a `ChildDialog`.  No `ChildDialog` is actually created so when you try to access it, you get a crash.  Rather you need

```
ChildDialog* childDialog = new ChildDialog(...);
```

With arguments to the constructor as required.